# Getting the correct sex count from a View

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-server-2016

I have a view results like this:

| Teacher_id | Sex | Missed_Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | m | 19-01-2023 |
| 37 | f | 19-01-2023 |
| 45 | m | 01-02-2023 |
| 78 | m | 01-02-2023 |

I would like a `SELECT count(Sex)` to give me results as follows as the Teacher_id = 45 is a duplicate so it is one male not two:

| Male | Female |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

Currently I am having this :

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Sex = 'm' THEN 1 END) AS Male, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Sex = 'f' THEN 1 END) AS Female
```

| Male | Female |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |

How do I write this query to give me the desired results by not counting sex twice of `Teacher_id`

Comment: `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` value of `Teacher_id` not `1`. The only `DISTINCT` values your `COUNT` has is `1` or `NULL`, which means that the resulting count will be `1` or `0`.

Comment: When you use conditional aggregation, `COUNT()` is implemented using `SUM()`

Comment: @PM77-1 huh? `COUNT` and `SUM` aren't the same, conditional aggregation or not. `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN database_ID <= 4 THEN database_ID END) AS Count, SUM(CASE WHEN database_ID <= 4 THEN database_ID END) FROM sys.databases;` don't result in the same value, for example

Comment: @Lamu: I meant `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` will get you conditional count.

Comment: L a **r n** u, @PM77-1 ...

Comment: The OP wants  *distinct* count, not a sum, @PM77-1 . `COUNT(CASE <expression> THEN 1 END)` and `SUM(CASE <expression> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` do end up with the same result, yes; but that isn't what the OP is after.

Comment: @Larnu - Even with my glasses on `rn` looked like `m` to me. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Larnu - Then I might've misunderstood OP's requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pregroup your view first:

```sql
select count(case when sex = 'm' then 1 end) AS male
, count(case when sex = 'f' then 1 end) AS female
,count(case when sex not in ('m', 'f') then 1 end) AS other
from (
  select distinct sex, teacher_id
  from yourview
) x
```

EDIT:
If you want to combine regular COUNT with count distinct, you can use the following construct:

```sql
select  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Sex = 'm' THEN Teacher_id END) AS m
,   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Sex = 'f' THEN Teacher_id END) AS f
,   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Sex not in ('f', 'm') THEN Teacher_id END) AS other
,   COUNT(*)
from (
    VALUES  (45, N'm', N'19-01-2023')
    ,   (37, N'f', N'19-01-2023')
    ,   (45, N'm', N'01-02-2023')
    ,   (78, N'm', N'01-02-2023')
) t (Teacher_id,Sex,Missed_Day)
```

This allows keeping duplicates but not counting them for some of the fields. COUNT DISTINCT has some performance implications, but for smaller datasets, it should be fine

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question although my real life situation is more complicated than that. I am still getting the other count still being add in. I will answer your question answered if I don't get another answer

Comment: I'm guessing you also want to count some other rows. Added another version which might suit your case better

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how this works, but it gives me the right results at the end.

Answer (score 1):

another approach could be to retrieve them as subqueries, something like this

```
select 
( select count(males.sex) as Male
  from (select sex from table1 where sex = 'm' group by Teacher_id, Sex) males
) as male,

( select count(females.sex) as female
  from (select sex from table1 where sex = 'f' group by Teacher_id, Sex) females
) as female
```

This way you can leave this counting out your main query

Look at this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XyYJ0jHY)

Comment: Your answer is true when I am only wanting to get the sex count but I think there is an issue if you counting other things in the same query as I am doing right now. Maybe explain further.